# jquery is working well, but why no data is posted in db?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, registration

i am trying to make a user registration request using qjuery and ajax to php controller, but i am suprised that the ajax success alerts with a successful registration but when i look in my db, no data has been posted! what might be the issue here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#reg-btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

var firstname = $("#fname").val();
var lastname = $("#lname").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var contactNumber = $("#contact-number").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var repeatPassword = $("#repeat-password").val();


if(!pregMatch(firstname)){
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Registration Failed',
        text: 'Alphabet And White Space Characters Allowed',
      })

}else{
    $.ajax({
        url: "../controller/log-reg.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            firstname : firstname,
            lastname : lastname,
            email : email,
            contactNumber : contactNumber,
            password : password,
            repeatPassword : repeatPassword,
            
         },
         success:function(data){ 
                if(data == 'reg-failed'){
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Registration Failed',
                        text: 'Something went wrong!, Try Again',
                    })
                    }else if(data == "email-taken"){    
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Registration Failed',
                        text: 'Email taken!, Try Again',
                    })
                    }else{
                        $("#register").modal("hide");
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Registration successful',
                            text: 'You are a registred member, you can login now!',
                        })
                        // location.reload();
                }     
         },
    });
 } 

})
```

})

**This is the .php file that handles posting data to db**
i have used prepared statement to execute queries

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
init_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();

$conn =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shopping_cart_with_paypal');

if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_repeat = $_POST['password_repeat'];

$emailQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$emailQuery->bind_param("s", $email);
$emailQuery->execute();


$result = $emailQuery->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo "email-taken";
    ;
}else{
    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, email, contact_number, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $passwordHash = md5($password);
    $insert->bind_param("ssssss", $first_name , $last_name, $email, $contact_number, $passwordHash);
    if($insert->execute()){
        echo "reg-success";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "reg-failed";
    }
    $insert->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

}

Comment: i have spent 5 hrs seaching the internet for this issue, but i have not found any helpful content, is there any tip?

Comment: You have 6 s in your bind_param method, but only 5 parameters. Pls turn on php error reporting and also log mysql errors somewhere, otherwise you will always be in the dark if something goes wrong! Btw, your query code only checks for your application error messages, not for php errors, this is why it reported success.

Comment: thank you @Shadow, i followed you suggestion and after struggling a bit i solved the issue